# obtaining passport windows live refresh token

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js, access-token

I am using the **passport-windowslive** module and I would like to obtain a refresh token so that when my access token expires I can use the **passport-oauth-refresh** module to obtain a new one, however, the refreshToken parameter in my Passport strategy keeps returning undefined and thus being saved as null in my DB.

I have tried adding the accessType and approvalPrompt parameters like so to no succes:

```
app.route('/auth/windowslive').get(passport.authenticate('windowslive', {
    scope: [
        'wl.signin',
        'wl.basic',
        'wl.emails',
        'wl.contacts_emails'
    ],
    accessType: 'offline',
    approvalPrompt: 'force'
}));
```

Any body have this issue before/know how to obtain a refresh token for this strategy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the `wl.offline_access` scope in order to get a `refresh_token`.